# How to establish a dynamic model relationship in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I need to establish a dynamic relationship but I can't.

The table design is as follows.

**Page Table**

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Hello world |
| 2 | Contact |

**Category Table**

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Electronics |
| 2 | Sports |

**Blog Table**

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | First blog |

**Links Type**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Page |
| 2 | Category |
| 3 | Blog |

**Links Table**

| id | type_id | relation_id | slug |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | page/hello-world |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | page/contact |
| 3 | 2 | 1 | category/electronics |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | category/sports |
| 3 | 3 | 1 | blog/first-blog |

**CODE**

**Controller:**

```
$links = Links::with('title')->get();

return response()->json($links);

// I need to get the "title" key.
```

**Links Model:**

```
public function title() {
    switch($this->type_id) {
        case '1':
            return $this->hasOne(Page::class, 'id', 'relation_id');
            break;
        case '2':
            return $this->hasOne(Category::class, 'id', 'relation_id');
            break;
        case '3':
            return $this->hasOne(Blog::class, 'id', 'relation_id');
            break;
    }
}
```

This state does not work because the model has not yet been formed.

**Error Output**

```
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null
```

How should I go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: just noticed, but in your `switch()` every case should return `belongsTo(Class::class, 'relation_id');` instead of `hasOne`

Comment: $this->type_id always coming up as null. Probably because the query has not been created yet.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing can be achieved by using polymorphic relationships.

```
pages
    id - integer
    name - string

categories
    id - integer
    title - string

blogs
    id - integer
    title - string

link_types
    id - integer
    name - string

links
    id - integer
    link_type_id - integer
    linkable_id - integer
    linkable_type - string
```

`Page`, `Category` and `Blog` model should define these relationships

```
public function link_types()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(LinkType::class, 'linkable', 'links')->using(Link::class);
}

public function links()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Link::class, 'linkable')
}
```

`LinkType` model should define these relationships

```
public function pages()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Page::class, 'linkable', 'links')->using(Link::class);
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Category::class, 'linkable', 'links')->using(Link::class);
}

public function blogs()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Blog::class, 'linkable', 'links')->using(Link::class);
}
```

`Link` model should define these relationships

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphPivot;

class Link extends MorphPivot
{
    /**
     * Get the parent linkable model (blog, category, page).
     */
    public function linkable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function link_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(LinkType::class, 'link_type_id');
    }
}
```

- [Eloquent Relationships - One To Many Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations)
- [Eloquent Relationships - Many To Many Polymorphic Relations](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)

```
$link = Link::with('linkable')->first();

$link->linkable->title;
```

Comment: I need to be able to give "title" key constant in JSON output. Since the JSON will be output, I have no chance to call the relationship.

Comment: How about using polymorphic one to many? I've edited the answer.

Comment: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object. When I debug it doesn't run SQL query. Therefore, no data is received.